# Save array into database

Tags: php, mysql, curl

I am getting error from inserting array into the database.
**Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'visiting students should consult thestudents should refer to the relevant sectio' at line 23 .**

Here is the array below

```
array
 'Choose by Subject Category or Module Code' => string '' (length=0)
 '
Back to Home page' => string '' (length=0)
 'International' => string 'visiting students should consult the' (length=36)
 'Undergraduate' => string 'students should refer to the relevant section of the UCC' (length=56)
 'Postgraduate' => string 'students should refer to the relevant section of the UCC' (length=56)
 'Credit Weighting' => string '5' (length=1)
 'Teaching Period(s)' => string 'Teaching Period 1.' (length=18)
 'No. of Students' => string 'Min 15, Max 30.' (length=15)
 'Pre-requisite(s)' => string 'None' (length=4)
 'Co-requisite(s)' => string 'None' (length=4)
 'Teaching Methods' => string '1 x 4hr(s) Lectures; Other (Distance Education Module - Up to 146hrs Self Directed Study).' (length=90)
 'Module Co-ordinator' => string 'Dr Peter Cleary, Department of Accounting, Finance and Information Systems.' (length=75)
 'Lecturer(s)' => string 'Staff, Department of Accounting, Finance and Information Systems.' (length=65)
 'Module Objective' => string 'To examine the management uses of accounting information and to enhance students ability to exert effective managerial control.' (length=127)
 'Module Content' => string 'Topics include; the accounting information needs of management, costs and pricing; estimating costs; the identification of key performance indicators; budgeting for control; capital investment appraisal and  implications for strategic planning and control.' (length=256)
 'Learning Outcomes' => string 'On successful completion of this module, students should be able to:' (length=68)
 'Assessment' => string 'Total Marks 100: Continuous Assessment 100 marks (Project/ Essay. Approximately 1500 words.).' (length=93)
 'Compulsory Elements' => string 'Continuous Assessment.' (length=22)
 'Penalties (for late submission of Course/Project Work etc.)' => string 'Where work is submitted up to and including 7 days late, 10% of the total marks available shall be deducted from the mark achieved.  Where work is submitted up to and including 14 days late, 20% of the total marks available shall be deducted from the mark achieved.  Work submitted 15 days late or more shall be assigned a mark of zero.' (length=336)
 'Pass Standard and any Special Requirements for Passing Module' => string '40%.' (length=4)
 'End of Year Written Examination Profile' => string 'No End of Year Written Examination.' (length=35)
 'Requirements for Supplemental Examination' => string 'Marks in passed element(s) of Continuous Assessment are carried forward, Failed element(s) of Continuous Assessment must be repeated (Resubmission of revised Continuous Assessment).' (length=181)
```

Below is the query.

```
//============== INSERT QUERY================//
$result = array();      
foreach($result as $snode){ 
$query = sprintf("INSERT INTO save_array 
       (ModuleCode,
        Homepage,
        International,
        ......) VALUES ('%s')",mysql_real_escape_string($snode)); 


foreach ($result as $key => $value) 
$query = $query . "$value"; 

 echo '<br /><br />'; 
mysql_query($query) or die($query."<br/><br/>".mysql_error());  
echo $snode. '<br />'; 
}
echo '<br /><br /><br />';
```

Any help would be appreciated to figure this out.

```
//================== New Updated Query Using Mysqli =============================

$result = array();
foreach($result as $snode){ 
$snode = mysql_real_escape_string($snode);
$query = sprintf("INSERT INTO save_array 
       (ModuleCode,Homepage,International,.......)VALUES ('%s')",implode("','",$result)); 

echo $query. '<br />'; 

foreach ($result as $key => $value) 
    $query = $query . "$value"; 
$result = mysql_query($query) or die (mysql_error());
}
```

I echo the query and seems to be inserting the right value into the right column but not executing into the database.

**Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'visiting students should consult thestudents should refer to the relevant sectio' at line 23**

Comment: Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions for new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun the [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the [**red box**](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help to choose. If you care to learn, [here is good PDO tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Comment: OK am just learning PHP so not really familiar with the old code and the new code.If I decide to use MySQLi does that mean I have to change all my PHP script I wrote to work with MySQLi or how does this work?? I'll have a look at PDO and see what I could get out of that.

Comment: Could you add the resulting query in your question? And don't use mysqli until the first problem is solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you're trying to save into **multiple** columns:

```
ModuleCode,
Homepage,
International,
Undergraduate,
...
```

with a single value `('%s')`

also note that `mysql_real_escape_string` takes a **SINGLE** value, not an array (i assume **$snode** is an array).
Also consider using `PDO` or `mysqli`.

You could do (just for example; dont know the $snode structure) and check the output:

```
foreach($snode as &$val) {
   $val = mysql_real_escape_string($val);
}
...VALUES ('%s'),implode("','",$snode)
```

**UPDATED:**

**I cant find a problem;** the query should be working.
I even created a structure of your table in my system (assuming **VARCHAR(256)** of every column) and your query-output worked (inserted) as expected..

```
$result = array();
foreach($result as $snode) { 

   foreach($snode as &$val) {
      $val = mysql_real_escape_string($val);
   }

   $query = sprintf("INSERT INTO save_array (
        ModuleCode,Homepage,International,Undergraduate,Postgraduate,CreditWeighting, 
        TeachingPeriod,NoofStudents,Prerequisite,Corequisite,TeachingMethods, 
        ModuleCoordinator,Lecturer,ModuleObjective,ModuleContent,LearningOutcomes, 
        Assessment,CompulsoryElements,Penalties,PassStandard, 
        EndofYearWrittenExamination,RequirementsforExamination) 
        VALUES ('%s')",implode("','",$snode)); 

   $result = mysql_query($query) or die (mysql_error());
}
```

run the above snippet **as it is**; dont change anything.

Comment: Hey sorry about that. I updated my code using mysqli and seems to be putting the right value into the right column but not saving it into the database.Dont kno what am doing wrong?

Comment: I tried your approach and am getting the same result am getting from @Jack's approach.:(

Comment: are there errors? call error_reporting(E_ALL); at the top of the script to bring'em'all (just for safety). Also i saw that you changed into mysqli_*. That was your only change? how about the connector mysqli_connect. Stick with mysql_* until the problem solved, then upgrade (to minimize the noise distracting the real issue)

Comment: So I have the error_reporting(E_ALL); in my code.I changed into mysqli because I thought it might make a difference to my query result.But am back to mysql for now till I have things fixed.I have the result of my query above.Please have a look at it.Thanks.

Comment: I tried snippet you made on the update post and it's still the same.Nothing is saving into the database.Frustration isn't the right word to use right now.Have reconstructed and tried many other versions of sample code I did and am still not getting it. Thanks so much for your help though,you have truly helped me a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Echo your $query and you will see.
It isn't a valid SQL statement.

Rule number 1,2 and 3 for debugging dynamic queries: Look at the query itself.

Comment: No, those are rules number 2, 3 and 4. #1 is not to use `mysql_*`.

Comment: I echoed my query and seems to be putting the right value in the right column but still not saving it into the database.

Answer (score 0):

You main problem is quotation marks:

```
('%s')
```

And then your:

```
mysql_real_escape_string
```

It causing conflicts in your SQL. Use either MySQL escape or '.

So what is happening is that your double escaping your SQL input which is causing it to actually SQL inject...

Also MYSQL real escape string will not insert $snode as an array. You will need to foreach the array extracting the values building and array to inject into the SQL query.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your array `$node` is in the same order as the columns you have shown, you can use `vsprintf()` instead to generate the resulting query:

```
// assuming $node is the array with the data
// generate list of place holders
$placeholders = join(',', array_fill(0, count($node), "'%s'"));

// construct full query using array_map applied to the escaping function
$query = vsprintf("INSERT INTO save_array (ModuleCode,
        Homepage,
        International,
        Undergraduate,
        Postgraduate,
        CreditWeighting,
        TeachingPeriod,
        NoofStudents,
        Prerequisite,
        Corequisite,
        TeachingMethods,
        ModuleCoordinator,
        Lecturer,
        ModuleObjective,
        ModuleContent,
        LearningOutcomes,
        Assessment,
        CompulsoryElements,
        Penalties,
        PassStandard,
        EndofYearWrittenExamination,
        RequirementsforExamination) VALUES ($placeholders)", 
            array_map('mysql_real_escape_string', $node)
);
```

Btw, don't use `mysql_` functions!